# Can an SD card with an image for an ARM32 system be read on regular linux

Tags: architecture, corruption, hard-drive

I am working on a microcontroller system that was hooked up to some motors. I am worried I had some back EMF fry something. I thought I would be safe by working off an SD card rather than internal flash memory. However after the event which was not crazy (just I know my board died) I cannot read my SD card on a Mac which runs linux.

I get a message "The disk you attached was not readable by this computer" Does that mean the files are corrupted or is that because the the card was flashed with a bootable image for an ARM SOC "Beaglebone Black" and not regular linux.

Am I screwed?

Thanks in advance